# Creating effective sqlite indexes to process statements with group by and many group_concat statements

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, group-concat

I'm trying to extract statistics from a sqlite db. I am basically collecting all possible variations and counts of variations for each column while the primary keys are grouped by a `group_id` column (many `skus` belong to each `group_id`).

For clarity assume a table like this:

```
sku, group_id, column_a, column_b
```

The query (abridged) looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    group_id, 
    count(sku),
    group_concat(distinct column_a),
    count(distinct column_a),
    group_concat(distinct column_b),
    count(distinct column_b),
FROM 
    my_table
GROUP BY 
    group_id
ORDER BY 
    count(sku) DESC;
```

My table has 8 million lines and 20 columns.

Currently the unabridged version of this query never completes (at least 20 minutes running).

I've added indexes on `group_id` and `sku` columns.

***EDIT***
my indexes are like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_group_id ON products(group_id);
CREATE INDEX index_sku ON products(sku);
CREATE INDEX index_group_id_sku ON products(group_id,sku);
```

Query plan

```
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE products USING INDEX index_group_id_sku
```

Number of group_ids

```
sqlite> select count(distinct group_id) from products; 
6426446
```

Number of skus (primary keys - row count)

```
sqlite> select count(sku) from products; 
8395475
```

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html). How many groups are there?

Comment: 0|0|0|SCAN TABLE products USING INDEX index_group_id_sku

Comment: sqlite> select count(distinct group_id) from products;
6426446

Comment: row count
sqlite> select count(sku) from products;
8395475

Comment: You could try a covering index on all four columns used, but that would not help with sorting the six million rows.

Comment: I have 22 columns

Comment: should I index all of them to a single index ? i..e CREATE INDEX big_index ON products(sku,group_id,c1,c2,....,c22)

Comment: `group_id` would have to be the first column. But for that, a [WITHOUT ROWID table](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) might be more helpful (but probably not if you're not grouping by the primary key).